# How to read an HTTP file line by line in C

Tags: c, http

I am wanting to pull from a plain-text file on the internet, and have it read line by line. Similar to how you read a file line by line with fgets(). I don't want to download the file. I know that if you use the read() function, you can specify how many bytes to receive and manually read the file line by line. I was just wondering if there was any way to do this automatically. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Using `http` you're downloading the file regardless — even if it's only in memory. I think you mean to say "that you don't want to save the file to disk"?

Comment: The process is a 2-step process, read the web page with `curl` and then process the text through a separate `htm2txt` file you can use with `execlp` or the like, for both and make use of `dup2` to handle creating/closing the multiple file descriptors needed.

Comment: Obviously I meant that I didn't want to save the file to the disk. There's no reason to be a smartass

Answer (score 0):

I have to do that a lot, and wrote the following little function to help. Just call **FILE *wwwpopen(), *fp=wwwpopen("http://wherever.com/whatever.html","r");** and then use **fp** as usual to read whatever.com any way you like. When done, just **pclose(fp)** yourself. Here's the little function (note: if wget not on your default path, then replace wget[256] initialization below by the full path to wget on your system),

```
/* ==========================================================================
 * Function:    wwwpopen ( char *url, char *mode )
 * Purpose:     popen("wget -O - url",mode)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   url (I)     char * containing null-terminated string
 *                          with url to be opened
 *              mode (I)    char * containing null-terminated string
 *                          that should always be "r"
 *                          (this arg ignored, always "r"; just there for
 *                          consistency with fopen/popen calling sequence)
 * Returns:     ( FILE * )  file pointer to popen()'ed url file
 *                          or NULL for any error.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o pclose(fileptr) yourself when finished reading file
 * ======================================================================= */
/* --- entry point --- */
FILE    *wwwpopen ( char *url, char *mode ) {
/* --- Allocations and Declarations --- */
FILE    *fileptr = NULL;        /* file ptr returned to caller */
char    defaultmode[16] = "r",  /* default mode, always used */
        wgetargs[16] = "-O -",  /* command-line args for wget */
        wget[256] = "wget",     /* replace by path to wget, if any */
        command[512];           /* constructed wget command */
/* --- Check input --- */
mode = defaultmode;             /* force popen() mode, must be "r" */
if ( url != NULL ) {            /* url supplied */
  /* --- popen() file --- */
  sprintf(command,"%s %s %s",   /* construct wget args url */
      wget,                     /* path to wget program */
      wgetargs,                 /* command-line args for wget */
      url);                     /* and url to be wgotten */
  fileptr = popen(command,mode); } /* popen() url (mode better be "r")*/
return ( fileptr );             /* back to caller with file ptr */
} /* --- end-of-function wwwpopen() --- */
```